# Chart Js , Stacked Bar label repetidos

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Necesito graficar un bar horizontal.
El problema es que me repite los labels

[image: Now]

**Es posible que solo se muestren una vez?
Actual:**

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["User1", "User2"],
  datasets: [
    {
      stacked: "test",
      label: "TotalTime",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [100, 100],
      yAxisID: "bar-x-axis2",
    },
    {
      stacked: "test",
      label: "Leave",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(191,191,191, 0.5)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [160, 160],
      yAxisID: "bar-x-axis1",
    },
  ],
};

var options = {
  indexAxis: "y",
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        id: "bar-y-axis1",
        stacked: true,
      },
    ],
    yAxes: [
      {
        id: "bar-x-axis2",
        stacked: true,
      },
      {
        display: true,
        stacked: true,
        id: "bar-x-axis1",
      },
    ],
  },
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

**Version : "chart.js": "^3.5.1",**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te adjunto una posible solución basado en tu código. He eliminado algunas configuraciones innecesarias y agregado otras.

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["User1", "User2"],
  datasets: [
    {
      stacked: "test",
      label: "TotalTime",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [100, 100],
    },
    {
      stacked: "test",
      label: "Leave",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(191,191,191, 0.5)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [160, 160],
    },
  ],
};

var options = {
  indexAxis: "y",
   scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Agregando un tercer dataset:

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["User1", "User2"],
  datasets: [
      {
      stack:1,
      label: "TotalTime",
      backgroundColor: "red",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [50, 50],
      yAxisID:1
    },
    {
      stack:1,
      label: "TotalTime",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [40, 40],
      yAxisID:1
    },
    {
      label: "Leave",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(191,191,191, 0.5)",
      borderWidth: 1,
      data: [100, 100],
      yAxisID:1
    },
  ],
};

var options = {
  indexAxis: "y",
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Genial! muchas gracias, si quisiera agregar otro dataset y que se stackee solo en el azul, es decir que el gris quede de fondo, y que quede por ejemplo la barra azul + un dataset rojo, se podría?

Comment: @nawelittle claro que se puede. Checa el ejemplo que te adjunté en mi respuesta a ver si es eso lo que querías.

Comment: Genial, me refería a que el gris quede de fondo, por ejemplo si el rojo y el azul tienen un valor de 50, y el gris es de 110, debería stackear las barras rojas y azules y superponerla sobre esos 110, es decir solo debería ver 10 del gris

Comment: @nawelittle ya entendí, ahí te lo dejo. Saludos.

Comment: Jaime, si agrego al objeto options.scales.y.ticks.color = red, repite el eje de Y, hay forma de cambiar el color de los ticks del eje de Y? sin afectar al renderizado